# When can we consider two different body as a Single system in mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I am High school Student. During ***Newton's Laws of Motion*** , my physics teacher said me that When two bodies have different acceleration then we will not consider those  two bodies as System.

Then my friend asked, *What will happen if magnitude of acceleration is same but direction is different* ?

Then our physics teacher replied that " in that case we will obviously not consider them as system because acceleration have different directions ".

So according to him, in these two cases :

[image]

We will not consider body A and body B as system.

Then after sometime, When i was attending an online lecture, I observed that a physics teacher choose two blocks as System shown in figure given below:

[image]

In this case , two block have same acceleration but in ***opposite direction*** , but still we are considering them as system.

So ***my Question*** is:

When can we consider two different body as a Single system in mechanics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When can we consider two different body as a Single system in mechanics?

Whenever it is convenient to do so.  It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

By creating a system, you can often ignore the forces between the components of the system.  They become "internal" forces and don't affect the behavior of the center of mass of the system.

But there's not a right answer that you always do it one way or another.  Usually for a physics problem there's a way that simplifies your calculations.

Comment: You said "They become "internal" forces and don't affect the behavior of the center of mass of the system" so we have *to choose the system in sach a manner that it doesn't effect the center of mass of system* ?

Comment: So i don't understand this line, you mean that we have choose the system such that Acceleration of centres of mass does not effect ; you means it should be constant?

Comment: That depends on the exact problem.  You can say that only forces external to the system (perhaps gravity?  Normal forces?  supplied force?) can accelerate the center of mass of the system.